# What's the error in this program code?

Tags: c

I tried using the ASCII code too by replacing `%d` with `%c` in `scanf() code. but then it displays - Add=5 (If I put the input 5 & 6 with 65 ASCII code)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    int num1,num2,res;
    char ch;
    printf("Enter two numbers");
    scanf("%d%d",&num1,&num2);
    printf("Enter the operator from the following\n\nA for +\nB for -\nC for*\nD for /\n");
    scanf("%c",&ch);

    if(ch=='A')
    {
        res=num1+num2;
        printf("Add=%d",res);
    }
    else if(ch=='B')
    {
        res=num1-num2;
        printf("Sub=%d",res);
    }
    else if(ch=='C')
    {
        res=num1*num2;
        printf("Mul=%d",res);
    }
    else if(ch=='D')
    {
        res=num1/num2;
        printf("Div=%d",res);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid Operator");
    }
    getch();
}
```

The output:

[image: Here's the Output]

Any help?

Comment: Do you know what "indentation" is?

Comment: How do you input "65 ASCII code" ?

Comment: Things you might want to include in the question: What, exactly, are you inputting? What result are you seeing? What result did you expect?

Comment: Read documentation of `scanf` ; you should test its return value (number of scanned items)

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: Notice that `main`  should be declared `int main(int argc, char**argv)`

Comment: Try by `ch = getchar()` to get input of character.

Comment: Imran I did what you said, but same problem.

Comment: @EugeneSh. like this
scanf("%d", &ch);

Comment: @AshishMasih I mean, what do you input in the console?

Comment: @PaulRoub The question is simple, you have to put the following characters, like A for +, B for -, so on. So if I Put A then it should do the addition and shows the result. But it's not taking the char input and shows suddenly the last else code.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I input first the two numbers for eg. 4 & 5, then press Enter, then it shows that printf code with last else code, then I press any key it leads me to source code. Kindly help me in this basic question as I'm novice in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rather write a more useful and correct version of this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n1, n2, ans;
    char op;
    scanf("%d %c %d", &n1, &op, &n2);
    switch (op) {
    case '+':
        ans = n1 + n2;
        break;
    case '-':
        ans = n1 - n2;
        break;
    case '*':
        ans = n1 * n2;
        break;
    case '/':
        if (n2) {
            ans = n1 / n2;
            break;
        }
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid Input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%d", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
1 + 2
4-3
```

**Output**

```
3
1
```

See http://ideone.com/y2nnWF demo.

Comment: Thank You! The one you write is definitely easier one than my one.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing, sadly, the same problem faced by every beginning C programmer ever: `scanf` sucks.  When you called

```
scanf("%d%d",&num1,&num2);
```

it correctly read the two numbers that you typed.  But after you typed the two numbers, you probably hit RETURN.  And the first call to `scanf` did *not* read that return character.  So it's still sitting there in the input buffer, and when you later call `scanf("%c",&ch)`, it's actually the newline character that gets read, not the A or B that you wanted to read.

Without changing your program at all, you can try typing something like

```
12 34A
```

in response to the first prompt.  The first `scanf` won't read it, so now *it* will be sitting there in the input buffer waiting for your second call to `scanf` to find it.

That's a workaround, not a fix.  To fix it, you could do what @Ediac suggested in his answer.

(A better fix would probably be not to use `scanf` at all, but unfortunately that involves learning more about I/O than your book or instructor probably wanted to get into right at first.)

Comment: omG  bro! It worked, so was my coding wrong? Can you explain that scanf issue in description, please?

Comment: @AshishMasih: Read my answer again, the explanation is in there. :-)  Your code was "wrong" in that you did not ask `scanf` to do quite what you wanted, but then, it is nearly impossible to get `scanf` to do what you want, for anything.  (Me, I never use it.)

Comment: thanks bro! I wish I knew this scanf issue already.